# How to update an Azure Service Endpoint using python?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, serviceconnection

Currently I have a python function that takes the information of an Azure DevOps Service Connection. The problem is that I want to update that, and using a PUT request I always have a body problem. I´ve tried to use Postman to test if it works, and it is. The problem only remains on the python code.
My code is this:

```
def update_sc_key(secret_value, app_name, sc_dependence):

print(f"SC DEPENDENCE:",sc_dependence)
personal_access_token = get_pat()
bearer = get_bearer()

if sc_dependence == True:
    
    pat_credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
    connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=pat_credentials)  
    
    service_connection_name = app_name[len('SP_') + app_name[len('SP_'):].find('_') - 4:]  
    print(service_connection_name)
        
    service_endpoint_client = connection.clients.get_service_endpoint_client()  
    service_connections = service_endpoint_client.get_service_endpoints(project_name)  
    
    for service_connection in service_connections:
        
        if service_connection.name == "RENEWAL_SC_TEST": # service_connection_name
            
            print(f'SERVICE CONNECTION NAME:', service_connection.name) 
            service_connection_id = service_connection.id  
            print(f'SERVICE CONNECTION ID:', service_connection_id)
            
            # Get Service Connection body
            project_url = organization_url + project_name + "/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints"
            
            try:
            # GET RESPONSE
             
                get_params = {  
                    "endpointIds": service_connection_id,  
                    "api-version": "7.1-preview.4"  
                }  
                get_headers={  
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + bearer  
                } 

                get_response = requests.get(project_url, params=get_params, headers=get_headers)
                get_response_tr = get_response.json()

                get_data_obj1 = get_response_tr['value']
                get_data_obj2 = str(get_data_obj1)
                get_data_obj3 = get_data_obj2[1:-1]

                if get_response.status_code == 200:  

                    get_data_obj_mod = get_data_obj3.replace("'authenticationType': 'spnKey'", "'authenticationType': 'spnKey', 'serviceprincipalkey': '" + secret_value + "'")  
                    get_data_obj_mod_rep = get_data_obj_mod.replace("'", "\"").replace("True", "true").replace("False", "false")  
                    get_data_obj_mod_rep = json.load(get_data_obj_mod)
                    print(get_data_obj_mod_rep)              
                    
                else:  

                    print(f"Error: {get_response.status_code} - {get_response.text}")  
            

                # PUT RESPONSE TO CHANGE PWD
  
                put_params = {
                    "endpointId": service_connection_id,  
                    "api-version": "7.1-preview.4"  
                }
                put_headers={  
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + bearer,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                } 
                put_body={
                    "body": get_data_obj_mod_rep
                }

                put_response = requests.put(project_url, params=put_params, headers=put_headers, data=put_body)
                
                print(put_response.status_code)
                print(put_response.text)
                
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print("ERROR: expired bearer token") 
            
else:
    print(f'No Service Connection')
```

The result of the variable "get_data_obj_mod_rep" works on Postman as I said, but if I use the same on python, I get this error:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: endpoint","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Comment: What kind of service connection are you using?

Comment: Azure Resource Manager using Service Principal

Comment: Manual type or Automatic type?

Comment: Manual. Just I need to get the response of the GET and use it body adding the "serviceprincipalkey" to add de SP key and link the SC with the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your python sample, I can reproduce the similar issue.

[image]

To solve this issue, I change to use another python format to get the service connection body and modify it.

Here is an example:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://dev.azure.com/org/projectname/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/serviceconnectionid?api-version=7.1-preview.4"


headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic Based64token',
}

get_response = requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers)
secret_value = "xxxxx"
get_data_obj_mod = json.loads(get_response.content)


get_data_obj_mod["authorization"]["parameters"]["serviceprincipalkey"] = secret_value

ref_format = json.dumps(get_data_obj_mod, indent=2)

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=ref_format)

print(response.text)
```

In this case, I can update the service connection successfully.

**Update:**

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/serviceconnectionid?api-version=7.1-preview.4"

get_headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic based64PAT',
}

get_response = requests.get(url, headers=get_headers)

secret_value = "test"
get_data_obj_mod = json.loads(get_response.content)

get_data_obj_mod["authorization"]["parameters"]["serviceprincipalkey"] = secret_value
ref_format = json.dumps(get_data_obj_mod, indent=2)


put_headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic Based64PAT',
}


put_response = requests.put(url, headers=put_headers, data=ref_format)

print(put_response.text)
```

**Update1:**

When we use the params as the sample you shared, the url will change to below format:

```
Put https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/?endpointIds=serviceconnectionid&api-version=7.1-preview.4
```

This is not correct.

The correct format:

```
Put https://dev.azure.com/org/projectname/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/serviceconnectionid?api-version=7.1-preview.4
```

This should be the root cause of the issue.

The following format will work too:

```
import requests

import json


project_url = "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/serviceconnectionid"
get_params = {  

       "api-version": "7.1-preview.4"  
}  
get_headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic Based64PAT',
}

get_response = requests.get(project_url, params=get_params, headers=get_headers)

secret_value = "test"

get_data_obj_mod = json.loads(get_response.content)

get_data_obj_mod["authorization"]["parameters"]["serviceprincipalkey"] = secret_value
ref_format = json.dumps(get_data_obj_mod, indent=2)

put_params = {  

       "api-version": "7.1-preview.4"  
}  
put_headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic Based64PAT',
}


put_response = requests.put(project_url, params=put_params, headers=put_headers, data=ref_format)

print(put_response.text)
```

**Update3:**

```
def update_sc_key(secret_value, app_name, sc_dependence):
    
    print(f"SC DEPENDENCE:",sc_dependence)
    personal_access_token = get_pat()
    bearer = get_bearer()
 
    if sc_dependence == True:
        
        pat_credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
        connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=pat_credentials)  
        
        service_connection_name = app_name[len('SP_') + app_name[len('SP_'):].find('_') - 4:]  
        print(service_connection_name)
            
        service_endpoint_client = connection.clients.get_service_endpoint_client()  
        service_connections = service_endpoint_client.get_service_endpoints(project_name)  
        
        for service_connection in service_connections:
            
            if service_connection.name == "RENEWAL_SC_TEST": # service_connection_name
                
                print(f'SERVICE CONNECTION NAME:', service_connection.name) 
                service_connection_id = service_connection.id  
                print(f'SERVICE CONNECTION ID:', service_connection_id)
                
                # Get Service Connection body
                project_url = organization_url + project_name + "/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints"
                
                try:
                # GET RESPONSE
                 
                    get_params = {  
                        "endpointIds": service_connection_id,  
                        "api-version": "7.1-preview.4"  
                    }  
                    get_headers={  
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + bearer  
                    } 

                    get_response = requests.get(project_url, params=get_params, headers=get_headers)
                    
                    response = json.loads(get_response.text)['value']
                    get_response_tr = response[0]
                    if get_response.status_code == 200:  

                        # PUT RESPONSE TO CHANGE PWD
                        
                        url = "https://dev.azure.com/****/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/" + service_connection_id
                        
                        get_response_tr["authorization"]["parameters"]["serviceprincipalkey"] = secret_value
                        ref_format = json.dumps(get_response_tr, indent=2)
                        print(ref_format)

                        put_params = {
                            "api-version": "7.1-preview.4"  
                        }
                        put_headers={  
                            "Authorization": "Bearer " + bearer,
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        } 

                        put_response = requests.put(url, params=put_params, headers=put_headers, data=ref_format)

                        print(put_response.status_code)
                        print(put_response.text)

                        
                    else:  

                        print(f"Error: {get_response.status_code} - {get_response.text}")  
                

                except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                    print("ERROR: expired bearer token") 
                
    else:
        print(f'No Service Connection')
```

Comment: I get this error:

    get_data_obj_mod["authorization"]["parameters"]["serviceprincipalkey"] = "test"
KeyError: 'authorization'

Comment: @gjgjgjgj14 you can change to use this format: `get_data_obj_mod['authorization']['parameters']['serviceprincipalkey'] = secret_value` use single quotes.

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: Can you output the content of the response? You can check if the authorization field is in the root level. When we use the format:  `requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers)`  to send request, the authorization field will exist in the root level. You can check if you are using the same format to send request

Comment: You can follow my sample to send requests and change values. If the sending format is changed, the returned format will be different

Comment: This is my response: https://imgur.com/a/A48VGEn

Comment: Got it. Wait few minutes, I will modify the sample

Comment: @gjgjgjgj14 Check my update. You can avoid using the **get_params** in the Get and Put Request. You can directly define the full Rest API url and use it in the Get and Put request. Then it will work.

Comment: @gjgjgjgj14  And I have shared the root cause of the issue in the upate1. You can check it.

Comment: But in your example where are your SC reference? I mean, in my URL I set the SC ID that I want to get and update, but in your code I don´t see where are you defining the SC.

Comment: @gjgjgjgj14 I define the SC ID in the URL. for example: `project_url = "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{serviceconnectionid}"`

Comment: @gjgjgjgj14 You can check if the sample can work for you now. Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I´m still testing! I´ll let you to know the result

Comment: get_data_obj_mod["authorization"]["parameters"]["serviceprincipalkey"] = "test"
KeyError: 'authorization'

I´m still having this error

Comment: Can you share the current output of the script and the current script sample?

Comment: I changed a bit the code and now I don´t have the KeyError, but I have another different. the code: https://codefile.io/f/XYEjtJFnV6

Comment: @gjgjgjgj14 Check the updated code in Update 2 .You also need to change the Get request params.

Comment: Using your code I can´t even see the "ref_format" response. I just get a JSONDecodeError.

Comment: In this case, it has no response code. I need to modify it again to meet your requirement.

Comment: I think the problem only remains on the PUT, because using my code (https://codefile.io/f/XYEjtJFnV6) I can perfectly get the SC info and also add the SP key. I still don´t know why using the same body on Postman it works.

Comment: @gjgjgjgj14 No problem. Check the update 3. Based all your requirements, I updated the code. Check if it  can work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256605/discussion-between-gjgjgjgj14-and-kevin-lu-msft).